# CSS relative path in Mozilla

Tags: css

i wrote this CSS code into an HTML file to running in firefox:

```
<style>
@font-face {
font-family: abc;
src: url('./../abc.ttf');
}
* {
font-family: abc;
}
</style>
```

but firefox doesn't find font.

although i did try this code too:

```
src: url('../abc.ttf');
```

but no effect.
i run HTML under Firefox 60.

my folder structure is:

E:/1/index.html
E:/abc.ttf

Comment: What is your folder structure? Otherwhise we cant help you with the path error

Comment: E:/1/index.html E:/abc.ttf

Comment: that's weird, the path "../abc.ttf" would be right under these conditions

Answer (score 0):

No need to include the initial ./ part, try this instead:

```
src: url('../abc.ttf');
```

Comment: It sounds like you're running this from your file system.

If your current URL is something like file:///path/to/your/page/page.html, is there actually a file at file:///path/to/your/abc.ttf ?

Comment: Marc, the files are: E:/1/index.html E:/abc.ttf

Comment: Right-click the page, click Inspect Element, then in the area that opens up, click on the Console tab. Are there any error messages there?

Comment: Have you tried any other browsers? Does it work in Chrome, for example?